# best way to access user session

Tags: php, facebook

What's the best way to access user session?  I tried to use `$facebook->getUser()`, but somehow, the app can't access my current Facebook session (perhaps because of different cookies?).  So, what's the best way to access user session?

Comment: have you initialised the SDK with your `app_id` and `app_secret`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have active session, then the best and the only way to retrieve current user id is `$facebook->getUser()`